# How to word a proof for sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $ \mathcal{E} $ denote the set of even integers and $W$ the set of weird integers. Show that $ W \cup \mathcal{E} \ne \varnothing $.

- A weird integer is $n+1=3k$

I know the number 8 works but how do I construct the wording of this proof.

Comment: Show that $\mathcal{E}\cup W$ is nonempty?  This can be done by showing that there exists at least one element in $\mathcal{E}\cup W$ which can be done by showing there exists at least one element in either of $\mathcal{E}$ or $W$.  Since $8\in \mathcal{E}$ one has $8\in\mathcal{E}\cup W$ despite $8\not\in \emptyset$, thus showing the lefthandside is not equal to the righthandside.

Comment: What are you asking? Their union is obviously non-empty, and your example shows they're not disjoint.

Comment: I was trying to figure out how do I word the proof since I already have an example that show that it works. @MathematicsStudent1122

Answer (score 0):

Given $\mathcal{E}=\{2m\;|\;m\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and $W=\{n\;|\; n+1=3k \text{ for some }k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$
We can take $2\in \mathcal{E}$.
Since $\mathcal{E}\subseteq \mathcal{E}\cup W$,
we have $2\in \mathcal{E}\cup W$.
So, $\mathcal{E}\cup W\neq \varnothing$ because there exists an element in $\mathcal{E}\cup W$.